# How to ensure that page has finished loading on a React site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests

Is there a way to make sure that a web page, coded in React, has finished loading?
The usual javascript tricks, don't seem to work for React, meaning that you cannot use safely these:

> document.readyState == 'complete' && jQuery.active == 0

We are working on automated tests and because of this, we cannot have access to client side code, so we cannot or should create callbacks etc, in order to get the info we want. The easy way is to use thread sleep, but this is very unreliable, frustrating, and bad practice. Is there another way, like executing a js script that will return such information?

Comment: In which way do you depend on the page to be loaded completely?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone needs this...

The approach below is the best to solve your problem.

```js
function Component() {
    const [loaded, setStatus] = useState(false);

    document.onreadystatechange = () => {
        setStatus(document.readyState === "complete");
    }
    return {loaded ? <Loaded />: <Loading />};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the new useEffect api coupled with useState can help you achieve what you want,

Something like the following:

Inside your functional component:

```
 function yourComponent() {
   const [isLoading, setLoader] = useState(true)
   useEffect(() => {
     // Here you can access your API to get the Network state instead on document ready
       setLoader(document.readyState == 'complete' && jQuery.active == 0)
   }, [])

   return (
     <div>
       {isLoading && <Loader />}
       {!isLoading && <OtherComponent />}
     </div>
    )}
```

then you can use isLoading state tu display a Loader in your JSX part and hide it if the readState changes

Comment: I don't have access to the functional components in order to do such thing. We are not creating the code, but testing it

Comment: it's end2end testing so we're using java with webdriver